# Besides socket timeout, how can I continue to run the script?

Tags: python, sockets

I have written a python script (using paramiko) which automates the CLI commands of the L2 or L3 device. I do the following stuff in the script,

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(ipAddr.strip(), username=usrName.strip(), password=passWord.strip())
# Create a client interaction class which will interact with the host
connect = SSHClientInteraction(ssh, timeout, newline, buffer_size, display)
time_out = 20 // in secs
connect.send ("CMD")
connect.expect ("#", time_out)
```

Here, the device takes more than 60 secs to execute the "CMD". Yes ofcourse the timeout will happen and the script will be exited. But I do not want that to happen and script to be continued to execute the next command (say CMD1). So instead of raising the exception upon timeout, I have overridden the code to execute next command. But what really happens is, the next send is executed only after the 60 seconds. So I am getting wrong outputs in the next expect. Can anyone tell me how can I interrupt the send such a way that the consecutive commands excute in right way???

Comment: Please post the rest of the code. How & where is the `connect()` statement implemented?

Comment: The "connect" is nothing but the object of SSHClientInteraction from paramiko. Please refer the paramiko package for more detail about that object info.